# How to clear/reset SharedPreference from an Activity using onBackPressed() Method from another Activity?

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, sharedpreferences, onbackpressed

So I have SharedPreference coded into (Activity 1) which allows the user to choose which activity is presented to them first on App Launch. The code works fine but what if the user wants to change their selection? When the user presses the back button to go back to (Activity 1), it automatically redirects them to the activity that they previously selected. How can I reset/clear the sharedpreference in (Activity 1) when the user clicks the "back button" on Activity 2 which calls the onBackPressed() Method?

## Activity 1

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int choice = sharedPref.getInt("default_activity", -1);


    if (choice == -1) {
        // show the option to choose the default activity to the user
        // e.g. dialog with list, then save the corresponding choice to
        // shared preference
        String[] activities = { "Activity 1", "Activity 2", "Activity 3" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, activities),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putInt("default_activity", which);

                        editor.apply();
                        launchActivity(which);
                    }
                }).show();
    } else {
        // start the activity and close this activity
        launchActivity(choice);
    }


}

private void launchActivity(int choice) {
    switch (choice) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_1.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_2.class));
            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_3.class));
            break;
    }
    finish();
}
```

## Activity 2

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), PreActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research and tries, I've found the solution.

## Activity 1

I declared the variable as Static

```
public static SharedPreferences sharedPref;
```

Then I changed the "GetPreferences" line of code

**FROM**

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**TO**

```
sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then I kept everything else as the same "Activity 1"

```
 sharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
 int choice = sharedPref.getInt("default_activity", -1);


if (choice == -1) {
    // show the option to choose the default activity to the user
    // e.g. dialog with list, then save the corresponding choice to
    // shared preference
    String[] activities = { "Activity 1", "Activity 2", "Activity 3" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, activities),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("default_activity", which);

                    editor.apply();
                    launchActivity(which);
                }
            }).show();
} else {
    // start the activity and close this activity
    launchActivity(choice);
   }
}



private void launchActivity(int choice) {
    switch (choice) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_1.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_2.class));
            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_3.class));
            break;
    }
    finish();
}
```

Then in Activity 2 & 3 I added a single line of code to the onBackPressed() Method

## Activity 2 & 3

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Activity_2.sharedPref.edit().clear().commit(); // This line references 
                                      //"sharedPref" from the activity (Activity 2)
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_1.class);
        startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found something to work. I'm pretty sure issue was due to the fact that you using locally scoped shared preference. You need to either use the default store via ```SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);``` or specify one via: ```SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the code to reset the shared preference in activity 2. The onBackPressed should do the returning to the previous activity for you.

Also, you may want to use the default shared preferences to ensure you are accessing the same preference store:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

and use those prefs in both activities

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
              .remove("default_activity")
              .apply()
   super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

Comment: I've tried it but it still redirects me to the previously selected screen. I'm guessing the sharedpreference was not removed.

Comment: @Kezxi, I think this is because you were not using the default shared preferences. Each activity was loading a new preference store. You could also use a named store via ```SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefStore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);``` for example.